# Next-auth failed during building nextjs app

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth in my nextjs app.

npm install and npm run dev works fine, and also the authentication works locally. But when I run the build command I get this error message:

```
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.d.ts:18:61
Type error: '>' expected.

  16 | export declare function unstable_getServerSession<O extends GetServerSessionOptions, R = O["callbacks"] extends {
  17 |     session: (...args: any[]) => infer U;
> 18 | } ? U : Session>(...args: Parameters<typeof getServerSession<O, R>>): ReturnType<typeof getServerSession<O, R>>;
     |                                                             ^
  19 | declare global {
  20 |     namespace NodeJS {
  21 |         interface ProcessEnv
```

My dependencies in `package.json` looks are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.6.1",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.3.3",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "8.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
},
```

The only thing I found during searching the web is this [bug-report](https://answers.netlify.com/t/cannot-deploy-next-auth-is-throwing-error/84496) 4 hours ago.
Could it be a bug in next-auth ?

Thanks for helping.

I tried to use different versions of nextjs and next-auth but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got information from a lead developer of next auth:

> A fix is going out via this PR: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/6595 - 4.19.2 should not have this issue anymore!